# Require 'mechanize' gem issue

Tags: ruby, mechanize, irb, mechanize-ruby

I can't seem to be able to use mechanize in irb.
Here is the error message returned when attempting to : `require 'mechanize'`

```
2.2.0 :003 > require 'mechanize'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mechanize
    from /home/harvey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
from /home/harvey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from (irb):3
from /home/harvey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

The gem has been successfully installed already.

Any ideas what is wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do you have `rubygems` required already as part of your irb initialization?  if not try requiring it first

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
```

Comment: yes, I already have 'rubygems' required. and that works and return 'true'.

Comment: and you are 100% sure that mechanize i installed in the current rvm ruby and gemset?

Comment: 'mechanize' is installed.

"Successfully installed mechanize-2.7.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mechanize-2.7.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for mechanize-2.7.3...
"

however, for some reason, it does not show in the list when i type "gem list" :-\

Answer (score 0):

ok, i could install the gem with simply : `gem install mechanize`

Before I was doing `sudo gem install mechanize`, which did not work.

Not sure why it would not work with sudo. I mean it does say the gem is installed, but it does not appear in the gem list.
I would still be interested to know why the instructions did not work previously if anyone knows.